# Javascript Regular Expression multiple match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use javascript to do a regular expression on a url (window.location.href) that has query string parameters and cannot figure out how to do it. In my case, there is a query string parameter can repeat itself; for example "quality", so here I'm trying to match "quality=" to get an array with the 4 values (tall, dark, green eyes, handsome):

```
http://www.acme.com/default.html?id=27&quality=tall&quality=dark&quality=green eyes&quality=handsome
```

Comment: Those parameters makes no sense.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a regex to do this.

```
var qualityRegex = /(?:^|[&;])quality=([^&;]+)/g,
    matches,
    qualities = [];

while (matches = qualityRegex.exec(window.location.search)) {
    qualities.push(decodeURIComponent(matches[1]));   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DPJAt/).

The qualities will be in `qualities`.

Comment: Use `window.location.search`, not pathname or href.

Comment: @kojiro Yeah, fixed that almost immediately :)

Comment: Where is *quantities* defined? :P

Comment: I'd have to suggest adding `$` to the ending class, and `^\?` to the beginning one, to account for `quality`'s at the beginning and end of the query string: `/[^\?&;]?quality=([^&;$]+)/g`

Comment: @RyanKinal Inside of a character class `^` (unless the first) and `$` are taken literally. I'd need to use `(?:$|[&;])`. Also, [my code works](http://jsfiddle.net/mLBhG/) *as is* if the `quality` GET param is at the start or end.

Comment: This works perfectly and solves the problems I was having!! So I think what's happening is that [^\?&;] matches either a ? or a &(and the ? needs to be escaped), but I'm not sure what the ; is for. And than following this is the quality= followed by what we are trying to match. The () instructs this to be added to the returned array and inside the () is the reqular expression that matches the end: either a & of the $ meaning the end; but I'm not sure I understand the ^ and ; inside the [^&;$]. And I guess the plus is needed to provide for the possibility of multiple occurences. Thank you again

Comment: @user You are close, but not exactly correct. The `;` is because it is a valid delimiter for GET params.

Comment: I used your first response to get the array I needed, which I don't see anymore: var window.location.search.match(/[^\?&;]?quality=([^&;$]+)/g); It works fine for me as far as I can tell; is there a problem with this? I use the value to the right of the equal sign in each array element the aformentioned statement returns. I ask because I see your current solution is a little different than the one line solution I first saw. Thanks!!

Comment: @user815460 It shouldn't really matter, only I made that capturing group optional so it may match something like `prefixquality`. Now it won't.

Comment: The given solution doesn't capture the quality parameter if it's the first parameter.

Answer (score -2):

A slight variation of @alex 's answer for those who want to be able to match non-predetermined parameter names in the url.

```
var getUrlValue = function(name, url) {
  var valuesRegex = new RegExp('(?:^|[&;?])' + name + '=([^&;?]+)', 'g')
  var matches;
  var values = [];

  while (matches = valuesRegex.exec(url)) {
      values.push(decodeURIComponent(matches[1]));   
  }

  return values;
}

var url = 'http://www.somedomain.com?id=12&names=bill&names=bob&names=sally';

// ["bill", "bob", "sally"]
var results = getUrlValue('names', url);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antoined/y8vh1w69/)

Comment: [This code has numerous issues parsing query strings](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell).

Comment: @zzzzBov     The code assumes a query string where the parameters begin with a `?` and each are seperated with `&` or `;` (the same format as the asker specified). Handling the many edge cases you describe in your blog post wouldn't be worth the complexity it added. Off course if you want to handle those edge cases jquery has a function for parsing a url into an object instead of implementing your own with DOM (like the asker specified).

Comment: My main point is: don't reinvent the wheel, use a library that does it correctly (or at least mostly correctly).